Resolving Path names in different OS's in Python
I what I hope is a relativly simple question, yet one I have not been able to find an answer to online. I am working on a python package that I hope to be compatible across diferent os. One propblem I am running into is diffent path names on windows vs. macos and linux. For example: pd.read_csv("data\data_file_a") would only work on windows as the file path would not be recognized on mac/linux. I could of course use a try/except cluases or maybe even some sort for os checker, but wondering if there is an easier way. I know pathlib exists, but havent found anything that would explian this sort of functioality.
Is there anything that would allow me define a non-os specsific way to reach a file that I could feed to functions like as pandas read function or a load texture function that require paths?

/ is a valid path separator on Windows, Linux, and MacOS. os.path (e.g. os.path.join) or pathlib can also be used to abstract this in a cross-platform way.


Modern Windows accepts both forward and backward slashes as path separators, so "data/data_file_a" will generally work everywhere 2) avoid handling paths as strings when possible, prefer using proper path objects


@sytech yes it does. thanks. dont know why i didnt find that.

You've mentioned pathlib so you can do:
from pathlib import Path

df = pd.read_csv(Path("data") / "your_file.csv")
print(df)

